# Android - unzipping zip files that are password encoded

Tags: android, passwords, zip

is it possible to unzip files that have been zipped using a password?

I have search and cannot find any examples or mentions in the docs.

A link to docs or code samples would be great.

Thank you,

Mike

Answer (score 7):

Refer to this question:

[How to unzip a password protected file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997835/how-to-unzip-a-password-protected-file-in-android/14997963#14997963)

It uses a zip4j lib which works perfectly fine on android:

```
try {
    File src = new File("/sdcard/abc.zip");
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(src);
    if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
        zipFile.setPassword("a");
    }
    String dest = new String("/sdcard/abc");
    zipFile.extractAll(dest);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are right, the java.util.zip package does not support password zipping and unzipping functionality. You have to find other ways to implement it yourself. I did help search a bit see if you find this link useful :)
http://blog.alutam.com/2009/10/31/reading-password-protected-zip-files-in-java/