# How to unzip a password protected file in Android

Tags: android, unzip

I want to unzip a file which is password protected.. I know how to unzip for normal zip files which are not password protected. There are some apps like [Winzip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.winzip.android) which does the same thing.

Can you guys point me towards some tutorial or something which i can use to implement this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to implement this function into one of your Apps you can use [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)-Library which supports AES 128/256 Encryption and Standard Zip Encryption. The way how to use it, is very similar to standard zip libraries in java.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the problem you mentioned and I found neither `Zip4j` nor `severzipjbinding` help me with this problem. After searching I found [This site](http://blog.alutam.com/2009/10/31/reading-password-protected-zip-files-in-java/comment-page-2/#comment-153361) very useful and straightforward to use inside in your code.

Comment: Its not working for me.. Its saying `ZIP not password protected.`